# How to make google spreadsheet refresh itself every 1 minute?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-finance

My google spreadsheet is using `GOOGLEFINANCE('symbol','price)` function to retrieve stock prices of my portfolio. Unfortunately, I have to refresh manually now. How can I make the spreadsheet refresh itself every 1 minute?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you're on the New Google Sheets, this is all you need to do, [according to the docs](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093329?hl=en):

> change your recalculation setting to "On change and every minute" in your spreadsheet at File > Spreadsheet settings.

This will make the **entire sheet** update itself **every minute**, on the server side, regardless of whether you have the spreadsheet up in your browser or not.

If you're on the old Google Sheets, you'll want to add a cell with this formula to achieve the same functionality:

```
=GoogleClock()
```

**EDIT** to include old and new Google Sheets and change to `=GoogleClock()`.

Comment: @rickcnagy I don't know if this still works as the "On change and every minute" setting appears to only update the NOW(), TODAY(), RAND() and RANDBETWEEN() formulas, not the entire worksheet

Comment: how can I use `now` ? just insert in a cell `=now()`? will this update the whole sheet?

Answer (score 13):

If you are only looking for a refresh rate for the `GOOGLEFINANCE` function, keep in mind that data delays can be up to 20 minutes (per Google Finance Disclaimer).

#### Single-symbol refresh rate (using `GoogleClock`)

Here is a modified version of the refresh action, taking the data delay into consideration, to save on unproductive refresh cycles.

```
=GoogleClock(GOOGLEFINANCE(symbol,"datadelay"))
```

For example, with:

- **SYMBOL:** GOOG
- **DATA DELAY:** 15 (minutes)

then

```
=GoogleClock(GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG","datadelay"))
```

Results in a dynamic data-based refresh rate of:

```
=GoogleClock(15)
```

#### Multi-symbol refresh rate (using `GoogleClock`)

If your sheet contains a number of rows of symbols, you could add a `datadelay` column for each symbol and use the lowest value, for example:

```
=GoogleClock(MIN(dataDelayValuesNamedRange))
```

Where `dataDelayValuesNamedRange` is the absolute reference or named reference of the range of cells that contain the data delay values for each symbol (assuming these values are different).

#### Without `GoogleClock()`

The `GoogleClock()` function was removed in 2014 and replaced with settings setup for refreshing sheets.  At present, I have confirmed that replacement settings is only on available in Sheets from when accessed from a desktop browser, not the mobile app (I'm using Google's mobile Sheets app updated 2016-03-14).

(This part of the answer is based on, and portions copied from, Google Docs Help)

To change how often "some" Google Sheets functions update:

1. Open a spreadsheet. Click **File** > **Spreadsheet settings**.
2. In the RECALCULATION section, choose a setting from the drop-down menu.
3. Setting options are:

   - On change
   - On change and every minute
   - On change and every hour
4. Click **SAVE SETTINGS**.

**NOTE** External data functions recalculate at the following intervals:

- ImportRange: 30 minutes
- ImportHtml, ImportFeed, ImportData, ImportXml: 1 hour
- GoogleFinance: 2 minutes

The references in earlier sections to the display and use of the `datadelay` attribute still apply, as well as the concepts for more efficient coding of sheets.

On a positive note, the new refresh option continues to be refreshed by Google servers regardless of whether you have the sheet loaded or not. That's a positive for shared sheets for sure; even more so for Google Apps Scripts (GAS), where GAS is used in workflow code or referenced data is used as a trigger for an event.

[*] in my understanding so far (I am currently testing this)

Comment: GoogleClock was deprecated in 2014. Are you sure this works?

Comment: Thanks Mogsdad, I discovered this as well.  I missed that point in the original response.

Answer (score 7):

GOOGLEFINANCE can have a 20 minutes delay, so refreshing every minute would not really help.

Instead of GOOGLEFINANCE you can use different source. I'm using [RealTime stock prices](https://financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs/)(I tried a couple but this is the easiest by-far to implement. They have API that return JSON { Name: CurrentPrice }

Here's a little script you can use in Google Sheets(Tools->Script Editor)

```
function GetStocksPrice() {      
   var url = 'https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/stock/real-time- 
   price/AVP,BAC,CHK,CY,GE,GPRO,HIMX,IMGN,MFG,NIO,NMR,SSSS,UCTT,UMC,ZNGA';
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

   // convert json string to json object
   var jsonSignal = JSON.parse(response);    

  // define an array of all the object keys
  var headerRow = Object.keys(jsonSignal);
  // define an array of all the object values
  var values = headerRow.map(function(key){ return jsonSignal[key]});   
  var data = values[0];

  // get sheet by ID -  
  // you can get the sheet unqiue ID from the your current sheet url
  var jsonSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Your Sheet UniqueID");  
  //var name = jsonSheet.getName();

  var sheet = jsonSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 

  // the column to put the data in -> Y
  var letter = "F";

  // start from line 
  var index = 4;
  data.forEach(function( row, index2 ) { 

     var keys = Object.keys(row);
     var value2 = row[keys[1]];            

     // set value loction
     var cellXY = letter +  index;      
     sheet.getRange(cellXY).setValue(value2);  
  
     index = index + 1;    
 });  
}
```

Now you need to add a trigger that will execute every minute.

1. Go to Project Triggers -> click on the Watch icon next to the Save icon
2. Add Trigger
3. In -> Choose which function to run -> GetStocksPrice
4. In -> Select event source -> Time-driven
5. In -> Select type of time based trigger -> Minutes timer
6. In -> Select minute interval -> Every minute

And your set :)

Comment: How would you modify this so that it would save (ticker, price) in each row? currently it only saves the price

Comment: @mchangun you want the (ticker, price) in the same cell or different one? (example: ticker H1 price H2)

Comment: Different cell, just to the left of the price. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with crypto updates. A kludgy hack that gets around this is to include a '+ now() - now()' stunt at the end of the cell formula, with the setting as above to recalculate every minute. This worked for my price updates, but, definitely an ugly hack.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same with the IMPORTDATA formula but it appears that it is not possible to use the NOW() formula within the first formula. How have you managed that?

Comment: I am also trying same but without any luck!

Answer (score 3):

use now() in any cell. then use that cell as a "dummy" parameter in a function.
when now() changes every minute the formula recalculates.
example:
someFunction(a1,b1,c1) * (cell with now() / cell with now())