# How do I make Google Sheets refresh every 60 seconds?

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have an ImportJSON script in my Google Sheets retrieved from [here](https://github.com/fastfedora/google-docs). Now I have code:

```
=ImportJSON("http://date.jsontest.com/","/time", "")
```

which simply retrieves the time right now. My issue is that it does not refresh automatically.

How do I make it refresh every 60 seconds?

Comment: this is similar to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928726/how-to-make-google-spreadsheet-refresh-itself-every-1-minute).

Comment: @noogui yes it is, but GoogleClock() is deprecated so that solution is not up to date.

Answer (score 2):

I use a refresh script with the google apps script.

First you need to generate a random number to trick it into thinking its a new link.

```
  var min = Math.ceil(0);
  var max = Math.floor(99);
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
```

After that you need to write to the cell you want to have the time

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

sh.getRange("A1").setFormula('=ImportJSON("http://date.jsontest.com/","/time", "","' + randomNum +'")';
```

Then you can set up the script to run whenever you want.