# Script to refresh every minute/hour a google sheets that contains importxml and importhtml

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am looking for a way to make my sheet update every minute or hour if minute is not possible, it would be very helpful. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928726/how-to-make-google-spreadsheet-refresh-itself-every-1-minute

Comment: Probably you want the time driven installable triggers https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable